# ReactJS Redux Asynchronous Actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, react-state-management

I have read through lots of tutorial about using redux in reactjs but there are still few things which i am missing. Below is my action method

```
export const uploadFile = (files) => async (dispatch) => {

dispatch({ 
    type: T.UPLOAD_REQUEST,
    payload:{UploadStatus:"InProcess"}
 });
axios.post(`${config.API_URL}/upload`, files)
    .then(res => {
        dispatch({ 
            type: T.UPLOAD_SUCCESS, 
            payload: { UploadResponse: res.data,UploadStatus:"Completed"} 
        });
    }).then(res=>{

        dispatch({ 
            type: T.UPLOAD_SUCCESS, 
            payload: { UploadResponse: null,UploadStatus:"Queued"} 
        });

    })
    .catch(err =>{
        console.log(err);
        dispatch({ 
            type: T.UPLOAD_FAIL, 
            payload: { UploadResponse: err,UploadStatus:"Error" } 

        });
    }
    ).then(res=>{

        dispatch({ 
            type: T.UPLOAD_FAIL, 
            payload: { UploadResponse: null,UploadStatus:"Queued"} 
        });

    })
};
```

this action uploads file on server and dispatches to reducer to make updates on UI. "UploadResponse" and "UploadStatus" are two state fields which i need to render the UI on frontend.

when request starts I set `{UploadStatus:"InProcess"}` to render a spinner. After the requests succeeds or fails i set this status fields to "Completed" or "Error" accordingly. this helps me to remove the spinner and render success or fail message.

when request succeeds and UploadStatus is set to "Completed" and a success message pops up on front end and after that user interacts further on component to re render the component, lets say I enter some text in textbox, what happens is UploadStatus still holds the value "Completed" and the message pops up again.

To solve this issue, i make 2 dispatches on each success or fail request response. e.g. you can see in above code, on call success i first dispatched   `{UploadStatus:"Completed"}` , and then `{UploadStatus:"Queued"}`to reset the status. it helps me in a way that on first dispatch i render the success message on screen, then i reset the Upload Status so that the message to not popup on further interactions on component.

But I have to render a div on frontend when UploadStatus is set to completed, and this div has to be there even after further actions on component. On my second dispatch the UploadStatus is set to "Queued" so the div has disappeared.

I will further add my component code below to explain my logic to render the UI

```
render() {
  return (
  <div>
   <div className="upload-sect">
   {
      this.props.UploadStatus=="InProcess"?<Spin/>: <></>
      this.props.UploadStatus=="Completed"? 
      this.rendermessage("success","uploded"):<></>
      this.props.UploadStatus=="Error"?this.rendermessage("error","Upload 
      Fail"):<></>
   }
  </div>
  <div>
    {
      this.props.UploadStatus=="Completed"?
      this.renderUploadResponse(this.props.UploadResponse)
      :
      <></>
    }
</div>
</div>)}
```

Below is my render message fucntion

```
//message is ANTD design control , which pops up message on screen for a 
//while and hides automatically 
rendermessage=(type,displaymessage)=>{

    if(type=="success"){
        message.success(displaymessage)
    } else if(type=="error"){
        message.error(displaymessage)
    }
}
```

I have used Antd message to popup message on screen which automatically hides after a set time of interval. https://ant.design/components/message/

So what i am missing here is that i can't find out a proper way to render UI on frontend based on state change.

i would handle this scenario simply without redux, like there i would have the method to send request inside my component, and inside there in success or fail response i would render a message directly from there, rather than setting the state and then rendering message based on state.

like below

```
 uploadFile=(files) =>{
 this.setState({UploadResponse: null,UploadStatus:"InProcess"});
 axios.post(`${config.API_URL}/upload`, files)
 .then(res => {
    this.rendermessage("success","File uploaded successfully.");
    this.setState({UploadResponse: res.data,UploadStatus:"Completed"});

 })
 .catch(err =>{
    this.rendermessage("fail","Failed to uploaded.");
    this.setState({UploadResponse: res.data,UploadStatus:"Completed"});
 }
 )
 };
```

I have simply handled the scenario, because the method to send request is inside my component, and i just called this method when upload button is clicked. This reduced my render code as well like below

```
  render() {
  return (
  <div>
   <div className="upload-sect">
   {
      this.props.UploadStatus=="InProcess"?<Spin/>: <></>
   }
  </div>
  <div>
    {
      this.props.UploadStatus=="Completed"?
      this.renderUploadResponse(this.props.UploadResponse)
      :
      <></>
    }
</div>
</div>)}
```

what i am missing in redux? I think this is a very common scenario which occurs thousand times in react application. so it should be as simple to handle. what i am missing is that i can't find out the standard way to use redux?

Am I right to think that your logic to render the component varies when you decide using redux instead of managing state at component level?

Can you suggest what should exactly be the title of this question?

**Updated**

**From the comment section below i have found that most of people are not understanding my question so i need to put up some more effort to be more specific.**

The given problem in my question is just one case which i have presented.There can be different workaround to solve this problem , one of which i have adopted and fix the issue, that i will come to later, but first let me emphasize on my question.

I have shown while managing the state at component level, I just handled the UI with much simplicity. e.g. on success or fail of my asynch call , i just called a method which render the popup on screen , so this popup was not attached to any state change , rather its rendered directly in result of an action. whether you use ANTD message or any other notification provider that doesn't matter , the thing is that it has to be disappear automatically (under notification provider functionality notification hide after a certain time interval)

so in normal (i am calling normal to reactjs without redux) reactjs I can achieve this behavior simply . e.g. render the message without any state change and i will disappear automatically.

but in redux i can't make it that simple. the details i have already put up in my question.

Now what solution i have adopted to solve the issue is as below

I have come to conclude that to handle it with redux i have to make two dispatches to handle the scenario , i made a very small change in my code , lets put it below so that you guys not to scroll up to re visit the code

```
export const uploadFile = (files) => (dispatch) => {

dispatch({ type: T.UPLOAD_REQUEST,payload:{UploadStatus:"InProcess"}});
axios.post(`${config.API_URL}/upload`, files}).then(res => {            
dispatch({ type: T.UPLOAD_SUCCESS, payload: { UploadResponse:res.data,
UploadStatus:"Completed",MessageToBeDelievered:true} });
}).then(res=>{
dispatch({ type: T.UPLOAD_SUCCESS, 
        payload: { MessageToBeDelievered:false} 
    });
})
.catch(err =>{
    dispatch({ 
        type: T.UPLOAD_FAIL, payload: { UploadResponse:err,
         UploadStatus:"Error",MessageToBeDelievered:true }  
    });
}).then(res=>{

    dispatch({ type: T.UPLOAD_FAIL, 
    payload: {MessageToBeDelievered:false} 
    });

})
};
```

So no big change , I just keep an extra bit "MessageToBeDelievered" in first dispatch after a success or fail call MessageToBeDelievered is set to true , so that to render the popup , and then in next dispatch it is set to false . pretty simple right ? .. I didn't change the UploadStatus in second dispatch , so its value remains "Completed" after a successful call , even after second dispatch. so the div which i need to show on successful call , appears and rests there , unless the UploadStatus goes to "InProcess" again.

No big deal. so again coming to the actual question , my question is

(i) Do i need to think differently about my UI render logic while using redux and while not using it.bcs i thought redux is just another way to handle the state and it shouldn't belong to the render logic of my component, but its making me think of the component render logic to be change a bit which i was not expecting from redux.

(ii) Apart from this popup message (which hides automatically) , so far i couldn't find any other scenario like this , but are there any other scenarios like this ? any example ?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question well, your main question is that why is the modal with the message `"success","uploded"` showing even when the component re-renders?

Comment: modal with message is showing up bcs the UploadStatus still holds the value "Completed" . my question is how to handle this kind of scenario while using redux. 
As i have shown in below code that how this can be simply handled in normal reactjs (e.g. without using redux). 
my question is that is there a different approach to render the UI when using react ? does the logic of my component render method changes when i adapt to redux ?

Comment: in normal reactjs , the modal to show up didn't actually need a state change , it appeared under the success or fail response of call. but while using redux i am not directly calling the method to upload file , instead i am dispatching an action method on my component and then calling this action method .. this action method doesn't know the html of my component , i can't popup the message in there from action method , so i have the only choice to set the state in action method and then render my component based on that state. 
in that way my modal with message is also dependent on state val

Comment: First off, you don't need use async keyword since you don't await anything. Is your notification logic `<div className="upload-sect">`? If so, wheres the logic that makes the pop up disappear? Could you put a sample on CodeSandbox?

Comment: i use the await inside action method but i just hide those  extra code to focus on the problem. inside <div className="upload-sect"> i have called render message method which displays a message and hides automatically (notification message). I have updated the code of this method in question please look. its an ANTD design control named "message"  . it popups message and hides automatically

Comment: @SILENT `First off, you don't need use async keyword since you don't await anything` - that's maybe true but only for this case. If you have set of actions and they are all async they can run parallel without waiting one for another. Await only means you have to sync returned value with this thread to use the value.

Comment: @Zydnar anyways this is not right now the problem, kindly help me on question , i am in real trouble

Comment: @Zydnar i think there is no problem declaring a function with a asynch , whether you use the await inside it or not , that wont cast any performance issue , its ok if you use await inside it , if you dont , if works like normal function

Comment: I wasn't commenting you and this is not what I'm talking about - I'm NOT talking about issues with async keyword, just the opposite of that - about gains. However if we're by your code take a look at few async approaches when it comes to make state update by mobx, redux-thunk, redux-observable and redux-saga, you will understand a lot.

Comment: The reason the message repeatedly pops up is because your state is still set to complete. Usually you would have logic that changes the UploadStatus after a certain amount of time or when the user press the cancel button buts its incorporated into your ANTD.

Comment: I don't use ANTD but does ANTD run onClose after the timer is finished? If so, dispatch a new state to clear your UploadStatus.

Comment: @Zydnar based off your logic, javascript should by default consider all functions async. However, I bet some additional background logic is added whenever async functions are ran. If you don't use it, don't insert.

Comment: @SILENT I haven't said there are no limits. You can kill eventaully CPU with any approach. But yes, maybe everything should be async by default - problem is syncing threads takes time and eg. some operations on arrays are better handled on single-thread, but without this exceptions... https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754

Comment: Can anybody please understand the core of this question ? .. The question is that why i am able to accomplish this task in normal reactjs while redux making this a hell for me. ?

Answer (score 1):

**Specific Solution**

The [ANTD `Message` component documentation](https://ant.design/components/message/) mentions an `onClose` (function) argument that you can pass to the control.

The `onClose` function you pass will be called by the `Message` component when it closes after the duration you specified.

You should pass a function that updates the `UploadStatus` property in your redux state to some value other than 'Completed' (e.g. 'Inactive').

**General Thoughts**

You don't have to use redux for all state. It's perfectly valid to mix component state with redux. I tend to use component state to store state that is only relevant for a single component and its descendants and/or is short-lived state. I use redux for state that is used by multiple components and/or longer-lived state.

If a component depends on redux state, you'll have to manage the relevant redux state in order to control the component's behavior on subsequent renders (e.g. as I've suggested above). As you've noted, this can make some things slightly more complicated than a solution depending on component state.

I don't know the full context of your specific example, but if the state you've shown isn't needed by other components, I would lean toward storing it in component state. If the state is needed by other components, I would store it in redux and take care of managing it as I suggested above.

Comment: please see my answer to this question

Comment: @umer I've updated my answer to provide some general thoughts on the topic of component vs redux state. I would like to note that SO is geared toward specific questions with specific answers, and also that replying to your own question with an answer that is actually just a clarification of the original question is frowned upon.

Comment: thanx @tex i have upvoted you answer as onClose event is also a solution , i solved it defferently though. i agree on the your Genreral thoughts about redux as well , in my case this state belonged to other componets so i had to keep it in store.

Answer (score -1):

With redux

Redux passes the UploadStatus property into your component. On every render (keystroke, etc) you re-render with UploadStatus and its respective ANTD's rendermessage. This causes rendermessage to run multiple times since rendermessage is used incorrectly.

Without redux

No prop is passed that gets rendered repeatedly. You only call ANTD's rendermessage once after the function is completed.

You have multiple options to deal with it.

1. Don't connect ANTD's rendermessage to UploadStatus. Just use it the way you already have it setup without redux.
2. If you must use redux,create a separate component to handle it and React's useEffect to trigger rendermessage.